# Is this first-order proof valid? $(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)\leftrightarrow\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Is my theorem wrong? If so where did I mess up?

The following first-order theorem doesn't feel right to me.

$$(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)\leftrightarrow\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$$

(Where $x$ is not free in $P$)

Particularly:

$\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)\rightarrow(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)$

I am trying to prove first-order identities to be able to make more effective proofs in the future for my personal study.

I produced the following theorems using rules of inference.

I also used two theorems, which I mention after the main proof.

**Theorem 1.1**

1. $\forall x Qx \rightarrow P$
   **premise**
2. $\neg \forall x Qx \lor P$
   **material implication (1)**
3. $\exists x \neg Qx \lor P$
   **theorem A (2)**
4. $\exists x (\neg Qx \lor P)$
   **theorem B (3)**
5. $\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **material implication (4)**
6. $(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)\rightarrow\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **deduction theorem (1)(5)**

**Theorem 1.2**

1. $\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **premise**
2. $\exists x (\neg Qx \lor P)$
   **material implication (1)**
3. $\exists x \neg Qx \lor P$
   **theorem B (2)**
4. $\neg \forall x Qx \lor P$
   **theorem A (3)**
5. $\forall x Qx \rightarrow P$
   **material implication (4)**
6. $\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)\rightarrow(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **deduction theorem (1)(5)**

**Theorem 1.3**

1. $(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)\rightarrow\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **theorem 1.1**
2. $\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)\rightarrow(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **theorem 1.2**
3. $(\forall x Qx \rightarrow P)\leftrightarrow\exists x (Qx \rightarrow P)$
   **biconditional introduction (1)(2)**

Theorems A and B are mentioned below for reference:

**Theorem A**:
$$\neg\forall xPx\leftrightarrow \exists x\neg Px$$

**Theorem B**
$$P\lor\exists xQx\leftrightarrow \exists x (P \lor Qx)$$

I will only show my proof of theorem B, but if requested I will show my proof of theorem A.

**Theorem B.1**

1. $P \lor \exists x Qx$
   **premise**
2. $\exists x Qx$
   **premise**
3. $Qx$
   **existential instantiation (2)**
4. $P\lor Qx$
   **addition (right) (3)**
5. $\exists x (P \lor Qx)$
   **existential generalization (4)**
6. $\exists x Qx \rightarrow \exists x (P \lor Qx)$
   **deduction theorem (2)(5)**
7. $P$
   **premise**
8. $P \lor Qx$
   **addition (left) (7)**
9. $\exists x (P \lor Qx)$
   **existential generalization (8)**
10. $P \rightarrow \exists x (P \lor Qx)$
    **deduction theorem (7)(9)**
11. $\exists x (P \lor Qx)\lor\exists x (P \lor Qx)$
    **constructive dilemma (10)(6)(1)**
12. $\exists x (P \lor Qx)$
    **idempotency of disjunction (11)**
13. $P\lor\exists xQx\rightarrow \exists x (P \lor Qx)$
    **deduction theorem (1)(12)**

**Theorem B.2**

1. $\exists x (P \lor Qx)$
   **premise**
2. $P \lor Qx$
   **existential instantiation**
3. $P$
   **premise**
4. $P \lor \exists x Qx$
   **addition (left)**
5. $P \rightarrow P \lor \exists x Qx$
   **deduction theorem (3)(4)**
6. $Qx$
   **premise**
7. $\exists x Qx$
   **existential generalization**
8. $P \lor \exists x Qx$
   **addition (right)**
9. $Qx \rightarrow P \lor \exists x Qx$
   **deduction theorem (6)(9)**
10. $(P\lor \exists xQx)\lor(P\lor \exists xQx)$
    **constructive dilemma (5)(9)(2)**
11. $P\lor \exists xQx$
    **idempotency of disjunction (10)**
12. $\exists x (P \lor Qx) \rightarrow P \lor \exists x Qx$
    **deduction theorem (1)(12)**

**Theorem B**

1. $P\lor\exists xQx\rightarrow \exists x (P \lor Qx)$
   **theorem B.1**
2. $\exists x (P \lor Qx) \rightarrow P \lor \exists x Qx$
   **theorem B.2**
3. $P\lor\exists xQx\leftrightarrow \exists x (P \lor Qx)$
   **biconditional introduction (1)(2)**

Comment: The statement you lay out at the start is one of the variants of the "drinker's paradox".  Though oddly, the implication direction you say you doubt is the one that tends to be *less* controversial sounding.  (For example: $P(x)$ is "student $x$ gets an A on the test", $Q$ is "class gets a pizza party".  The direction you're concerned with would be: suppose there's some student who's been struggling, and the teacher promises if that student (whoever they are) gets an A, then the whole class gets rewarded with a pizza party.  Now, everybody in the class gets an A...

Comment: Then the conclusion is that the class gets a pizza party.  (The other direction is the one that sounds odd at first: Suppose the teacher promised that if everybody in the class gets an A, they will get a pizza party.  Then there's some student such that if that student got an A, then the class got a pizza party.  The reason that sounds weird is the difference between the "material implication" being used in mathematical logic, and a "causational implication" which you might inaccurately think of as the interpretation of implication.)